# JMeter - Define and use 100 distinct users to send HTTP request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a simple JMeter Testplan which shall send an HTTP request
with basic authentication. I have defined an HTTPAuthorizationManager with
100 users and their passwords. Plan is that JMeter runs this Test Plan
indefinitely with 100 distinct users and shall use all 100 users defined in the
HTTPAuthorization Manager. It basically executes that but only uses the
credentials of the first user in the list and not all of them. So in my application
I see only HTTP requests of the first listed user.

How to configure the TestPlan that it uses all 100 users defined in the
HTTPAuthorizationManager and not only the first in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a setup like this:

[image]

it won't iterate all usernames, you need to:

1. Add a [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to your test plan and point it to the file with your username/password combinations:

   [image]
2. Remove all these 100 lines from the HTTP Authorization Manager and replace them with a single line with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) defined in the CSV Data Set Config:

   [image]

This way each user will read next line from CSV file on each iteration and JMeter Variables placeholders will be replaced with the respective values fom the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataSet with all the user/password, maybe in a csv file.

Then, create a thread with the HTTPAuthorization Manager and the HTTP request, and repeat the thread. If you set the HTTPAuthorization Manager with one value, and the value is the variable from the DataSet, each iteration of the thread will take the next value of user/password

Something like this:
[image]